# Web Api 2 not find controller action

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I have the following controller:

```
public class RecordController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [ActionName("latest")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetLatest()
    {
        var record = recordRepository.GetLast();
        return Ok<MyRecord>(record);
    }
}
```

And the WebApiConfig:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "ApiByAction",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
            defaults: new { action = "Get" },
            constraints: null
        );
    }
}
```

The url i'm trying to access is:

```
http://localhost/api/record/latest
```

However, I'm getting a `404 Not Found` response code.

What could be missing? Is it the routing template?

Answer (score 0):

your example is working fine for me. Is there any port number associated with the url?

For example :

> http://localhost:**1234**/api/record/latest

Visual studio will try to use some port number every time an application starts.